# OpenSSL File encryption in PHP and decrypting in C++

Tags: php, c++, file, encryption, openssl

How do I encrypt a file contents in PHP using OpenSSL and decrypt it in C++?
Here's my code:

```php
$dll = file('file.dll')[0];

$iv = substr(hash('sha256', 'test'), 0, 16);
$key = substr(hash('sha256', 'test'), 0, 32);

$dll_en = openssl_encrypt($dll, "AES-256-CBC", $key, 0, $iv);
```

and here's c++

```c
int main() {
    /* A 256 bit key */
    byte* key = (byte*)"9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015";
    /* A 128 bit IV */
    byte* iv = (byte*)"9f86d081884c7d65";

    std::vector<byte> data = base64_decode("CyeJtJecBChtVSxeTLw9mYKapHwLNJed/5VVuyGOHNSTksBzH1Ym2JwLJv/LvlT9tqMEahwcX7Yj9jYVRCSnTliz/zQYk0pIi8CKTEGkqffqZd8CdA6joLMl9Ym6d+5wERgHEotURq8Kn+H3/GbUuEBUtLL9Cd1+VsKWDyqkE1c=");
    byte* ciphertext = new byte[data.size()];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        ciphertext[i] = data.at(i);
    }

    byte decryptedtext[8096];
    int decryptedtext_len;

    decryptedtext_len = decrypt(ciphertext, data.size(), key, iv, decryptedtext);
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = 0;

    std::cout << decryptedtext;

    return 0;
}
```

The decrypt function is from [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption)

The first line of the dll is
`MZ����@�� �!�L�!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.`
but all I get in console is `MZÉ`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Static IVs are a really bad idea, and IVs derived from the key are a worse idea, and IVs that are literally a substring of the key are a _catastrophically bad idea_. IVs should be randomly generated per-message and are usually packed into the first N bytes of the message as they themselves should not be considered a secret.

Comment: As there is no direct message system so I could contact you, would you please email me on shokarta@gmail.com? There is something I would like to cooperate with you Hopefully admins can keep this post at least for a while so user can contact me. Or if there is a way stackoverflow can contact users directly in any way, please share how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong except your choice of output method!

Since you're passing a `byte*` to `std::cout`, the only way it knows when to stop is to treat the input as a C-string, a sequence of 8-bit bytes. When it encounters one with value ZERO, it thinks it's a null terminator and stops. It's working as it should.

But your input is not ASCII! It is arbitrary, "binary" data.

You should instead use something like `std::cout.write(decryptedtext, decryptedtext_len)`, which just chucks *all* your bytes out to the output stream. It's then up to your console/teletype/printer to render that as it deems fit (which may still not be identical to what you're looking for, depending on settings).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, you just get things in ASCII instead of UTF-8 while printing a binary file, and characters are skipped until a `00` valued byte is encountered rather than printed out with as a diamond with a question mark. Perform a binary compare instead.

Of course you should note that key and IV calculation of the key and even more the IV is entirely insecure in PHP mode and that CBC mode doesn't provide authentication, so the code is not as secure as it should be.

Comment: _"you just get things in ASCII instead of UTF-8 while printing a binary file"_ That's not strictly true, but it is close to the right explanation for why streaming ends at the first null byte (via _history_)